# Node-Red mqtt server won't connect

Tags: node.js, mqtt, node-red

I installed node red on my windows machine and when i deploy it and start to configure mqtt node in, and when i deploy it constantly writes[image: disconnected and in cmd it shows connection failed to broker]

mqtt configuration is next:

- server: 127.0.0.1
- port 1883 topic
- sensors/#
- qos 0

Comment: And you have a MQTT broker installed and running on the Windows machine?

Answer (score 0):

Node-RED does not include it's own MQTT broker.

You will need to install one or configure Node-RED to point to one on a different machine.

There is a Node that will add a broker to Node-RED if needed which can be found [here](https://flows.nodered.org/node/node-red-contrib-mqtt-broker)

Comment: @hardlib i installed it, but still won't connect. in the dashboard/pallete i have node-red-contrib-mqtt-broker 0.2.1  mosca in

Comment: You have to drag one instance of the node on to the canvas and deploy it for it to start the broker

Comment: @hartlib, i did that.maybe it shouldn;yt be localhost, for me on my machine for node red i have internal ip address 127.0.0.1:1880 and for broker i put localhost:1883